# set to listView in asynctask class

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, adapter

i'm new in android and i want to do this but i have problem.
i have many adaper that can load to any ListView and i just want to do this in AsyncTask. my every adapter is like this :

```
 package com.example.mohammad.workclock;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import com.example.mohammad.workclock.Tbls.Projects;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;


public class projectAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

private List<Projects> listProject = new ArrayList<>();

private ListView listView;
public projectAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listProject.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return listProject.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    View Row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemsproject, parent, false);

    listView = (ListView) parent;


    TextView Txt_Title = (TextView) Row.findViewById(R.id.txt_Title);
    Projects P = (Projects) getItem(position);
    Txt_Title.setText(P.getTitle());

    return Row;
}


public void upDateInputData(List<Projects> listProject) {
    this.listProject = listProject;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

for load data to ListView i have class that do this in AsyncTask and this is the class:

```
       class loadAsyncTaskToListView  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<T>> {
        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        private Context context;
        private T adapter;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private String tableName;
        private N object_;

        public loadAsyncTaskToListView(Context context, T adapter, N object, String tableName){
            this.context = context;
            db = getReadableDatabase();
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.tableName = tableName;
            this.object_ = object;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.context, "","در حال بارگذاری");
        }


        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String Query = " SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
            List<N> ListTobject = new ArrayList<>();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                do {
                    N object = this.object_;
                    for (Field field : listField) {

                        Annotation AnnotationF = field.getAnnotation(AnnotationPartialClass.field.class);
                        AnnotationPartialClass.field fieldAnnotation = (AnnotationPartialClass.field) AnnotationF;

                        field.setAccessible(true);

                        setvalueToobject(object, field, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(fieldAnnotation.NameField())));



                    }

                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            return (ArrayList<T>) ListTobject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<T> inputObjects) {
            ((projectAdapter)adapter).upDateInputData((List<Projects>) inputObjects);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        public <N>void setvalueToobject(N object, Field field, Object fieldValue){
                field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                field.set(object, fieldValue);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

know when i want to use this method write this code in my activity:

```
projectAdapter dd = new projectAdapter(this);
LV.setAdapter(dd);
// LV is my ListView
LoadToListView(LV,dd, new Projects(),"");
```

when i run the code i have error list this :

```
08-18 13:18:28.999 26047-26163/com.example.mohammad.workclock 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Process: com.example.mohammad.workclock, PID: 26047
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field com.example.mohammad.workclock.Tbls.Projects.ID has type int, got java.lang.String
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.example.mohammad.workclock.AsyncTask.WholeWorWithDb$1loadAsyncTaskToListView.setvalueToobject(WholeWorWithDb.java:383)
                                                                                at com.example.mohammad.workclock.AsyncTask.WholeWorWithDb$1loadAsyncTaskToListView.doInBackground(WholeWorWithDb.java:357)
                                                                                at com.example.mohammad.workclock.AsyncTask.WholeWorWithDb$1loadAsyncTaskToListView.doInBackground(WholeWorWithDb.java:306)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

how can i fix that?

Comment: my error is in this method setvalueToobject in this line field.set(object, fieldValue);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As listed in your logcat, the problem is here:
**field com.example.mohammad.workclock.Tbls.Projects.ID has type int, got java.lang.String**
So you are expecting **int**, but having **String** instead.

P.S. This seems like a jackpot:
ListView + AssyncTask + reflection)
Try to avoid all this stuff in the future

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in this line

```
setvalueToobject(object,field,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(fieldAnnotation.NameField())));
```

In your "Projects" class there may be many fields with different data types.
But you are sending field value as string only.(i.e. your Field of type Int and you are trying to store a string value in it.)
So If there is any field of different data type. Then you get this Exception.

So you should first check the type of your field by field.getType() method and then send your field value of that type to "setvalueToobject" Method.

I hope it will work.